# RESTful webservice callout with method parameters in Salesforce

Tags: apex, apexrest

I know when a REST callout is made the request body can be found in requestBody property of RestRequest class. However, this property contains body only when the method doesn't have any parameters. Like below:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/testing/*')
global class Testing_response{

    @HttpPost
    global static String testing(){
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        System.debug('request body : '+ req.requestBody);
        }
    }
```

Can someone please explain how can we call method that contains parameters? like below:

```
 @HttpPost         
 global static String testingWithArg(String s, Integer k){
 }
```

I would then like to deserialize this request parameters. I know how everything works when the method doesnt have any parameters.

Comment: try sending a sample post data which looks like this {“s”:”stringResponse”,”k”:”123”}, and display the values using system.debug, i think this should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to deserialize the parameters, APEX would do it for you if you have sent in the parameters in the expected format.

> If the Apex method has no parameters, Apex REST copies the HTTP
>   request body into the RestRequest.requestBody property. If the method
>   has parameters, then Apex REST attempts to deserialize the data into
>   those parameters and the data won't be deserialized into the
>   RestRequest.requestBody property.

You might want to check the examples provided at [this link](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_rest_methods.htm) Apart from primitives, you can also send in sOjbects and List/Map of primitives/sObjects (of course with some considerations!)

In your case, you simply need to send in post data which looks like this

```
{“s”:”stringResponse”,”k”:123}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works the way you explained. Can you also tell me how can I pass sObject or List of sObjects instead of primitive data types. I mean, this has to be sent in JSON format right? 
If the method is like this:
         @HttpPost
          global static String testingWithArg(Account acc){}

The data should be in this format :



          string j = '{"acc":,"Name":"HAMAS MOTOR A/S","Phone":"12345"}';

Comment: it should look like this: string postAccountData = '{"acc": {
        "Name": "Hamas Motor",
         "Phone": 12345,
        "Website": "www.site1.com"
    }}'